# XJC doesnt generate main class from xsd

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I'm completely new in XJC and JAXB. I read a lot, but can't solve my problem.
I have an XSD file, that is a WS message. My XSD doc days: "The subscriber will respond with OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS message(s), indicating the success or failure status of the transaction(s)."

So I'm trying to generate the JAVA model based on my xsd file (OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS.xsd)
But when I generate java, it creates a lot of java classes, but no one of them are OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS.java or similar in which I want to hold the message.

command line I write:

```
xjc -p RS   OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS.xsd
```

XSD file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="2.000" id="OTA2011A">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="OTA_HotelCommonTypes.xsd"/>
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">All Schema files in the OpenTravel Alliance specification are made available according to the terms defined by the OpenTravel License Agreement at http://www.opentravel.org/Specifications/Default.aspx.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS" type="MessageAcknowledgementType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS is the message used to indicate the status of processing the OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRQ message.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I hold the message in a Java class?

Comment: Plz can someone help me?

Comment: Check if you have MessageAcknowledgementType class

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have similar issue with OTA_HotelAvailNotif_RS @Wijixx